# Not in query with Parse.com API

Tags: parse-platform

Given the Objects:

_User: (id, name, etc)

Trip: (id, _user, startDate, endDate, notes)

Is it possible to use the Parse Javascript API to find users who don't have any trips? In SQL it would be:

```
SELECT * FROM _User WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT _User FROM Trips)
```

Is that possible in Parse without selecting all users and then checking whether each one has trips?

Perhaps the question is better expressed in code:

```
var Trip = Parse.Object.extend("Trip");
var innerQuery = new Parse.Query(Trip);
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

query.doesNotMatchQuery("???", innerQuery);
query.find({
  success: function(users) {
    users.forEach(function(u){
      console.log(u.get('name')); 

      });
  }
});
```

What should go in the ??? `User`, `_User` and `id` return all Users, not those where there are no Trips.

Comment: Dear Lewis42, which API currently are you using? ios? android? REST API? javascript? php?  I do not understand what you mean Parse API?

Comment: It's Javascript, I've added it to the question. I'd just assumed the APIs in all languages had pretty much the same methods available to them, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used promises for this and can find no way to do it 'out of the box'. It's almost certainly best to wrap this up into cloud code.

Here's some sample code:

```
// Setup outer query
var query = new Parse.Query("Trip");
query.include('nomad');

query.find().then(function(tripsStartingNextWeek) {
  var promises = [];

  tripsStartingNextWeek.forEach(function(t){
    promises.push((function(t){

      var promise = new Parse.Promise();

      var toNomad = t.get('nomad');

      // inner query
      var myFutureTrips = new Parse.Query("Trip");
      myFutureTrips.notEqualTo('deleted', true);

      myFutureTrips.find().then(function(futureTrips) {
        // these records match both queries
        if (futureTrips.length > 0) {
          // do something
        } else {
          // do something else
        }

        promise.resolve();
      });

      return promise;
    })(t));
  });

  return Parse.Promise.when(promises);
})
.then(function() {
  status.success("Last trip job finished");
});
```